# Bash: exit a script when a specified folder is empty via the find command

Tags: bash

I want to check whether a folder is empty. If yes, write a log file and exit the script.

My code is below:

```
find $folder -maxdepth 0 -empty -exec echo [`date`] $folder is empty > log.txt & exit 0 \;
```

However, I received that

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

Could you please help me to figure out the problem?

Thanks!

===========================================================

**EDIT:**

Thanks for all of you!

I just tried only to exit the script without output log:

```
find $folder -maxdepth 0 -empth -exec exit 0 \;
```

or

```
find $folder -type d -empty -exec exit 0 \;
```

I received error:

```
find: ‘exit’: No such file or directory
```

And the script keeps running even I have put `set -e` at the top of the script. 
I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: `&` is a command separator. Your shell is running ```find $folder -maxdepth 0 -empty -exec echo [`date`] $folder is empty``` as one command (in the background because it's terminated by `&`), with its output directed to `log.txt`, and `exit 0 \;` as a second, separate command. Because there's no `;` or `{}` `+` following `-exec` *as part of the same command*... well, there's your problem.

Comment: Remove the `& exit 0` part.

Comment: `exit` is *built into the shell*. It's not an external command. `find` is not a part of the shell, so it has no access to shell builtins; it can only run commands that have their own separate executables (and these commands, because they're run as independent executables, can't change the shell's own state -- can't set variables in it, or tell it to exit, or so forth).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, this should work:

```
if find "$folder" -maxdepth 0 -empty | grep -q "."; then
    echo "[$(date)] $folder is empty" > log.txt    # Should this be >> to append?
    exit 0
fi
```

Explanation: if the directory `$folder` is empty, the `find` command prints its path; `grep` checks to see whether it got anything ("`.`" is a pattern that matches any character), and exits with a success status if there was a match; the `if` statement then runs or skips its content based on `grep`'s exit status.

Explanation of why the original didn't work: the command in `-exec` is not a full shell command, it's just a series of words that're going to be passed to the [`execl()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execl) system call (or a related function). That is, it's a filename of an executable (to be found in the usual `PATH`) followed by a list of arguments to be passed to it.

This has two important implications: you can't use *any* shell features in the command, so no redirects (`> log.txt`), no multiple commands joined by `&` or `;` or `|` or anything like that, no variable substitutions, etc. In the case of your command, all of those things will get parsed by the shell *before* passing the result to `find` -- so the redirect to log.txt happens to the entire `find` command, the `date` substitution happens before `find` is run, the `&` puts the find command in the background and treats the part after as a completely different command.

Furthermore, `exit` is not a regular command that can be run with `execl()` or such; it's a shell builtin (try `type -a exit`), and so it cannot be executed by `-exec`. And even if it could, it wouldn't do what you want, because the command run by `-exec` is run as a subprocess, and it would just exit that subprocess, not the entire script (or even the `find` command).

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It works for my purpose and helps me understand the issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

Like this, no need `find -maxdepth 0` :

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s dotglob # enable globing even with .hidden files

for dir in */; do
    if ! stat $dir/* &>/dev/null; then 
        echo "[$(date)] $dir is empty" | tee log.txt
        break
    fi
done
```

Comment: What does the OP expect the `exit 0` to do? If they expect it to cause `find` to stop processing additional files, they're going to be surprised.

Answer (score 0):

I think (now) you want the following:

```
# Exit if the current folder is empty
if [ $(find "${folder}" -maxdepth 0 -empty | wc -c) -gt 0 ] ; then
    printf "[%s] %s is empty\n" "$(date)" "${folder}" >> log.txt
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: Yes! But I am also looking for exiting the script.

Answer (score -2):

Try with a {} +

like this

```
find $folder -maxdepth 0 -empty -exec echo [`date`] $folder is empty {} + > log.txt & exit 0
```

Comment: find $folder -maxdepth 0 -empty -exec echo [`date`] $folder is empty {} + > log.txt & exit 0

The last part \; was giving the error

Comment: I tried several ways, but I cannot fix this issue. Any suggestion? Thx!

Comment: have you declared the variable folder with the name of an empty folder?